# CPU load of my program

Tags: c, linux, performance, unix

How can we know that how much load does our program is on CPU?

I tried to find it using htop. But htop wont give the cpu load. It actually gives the cpu utilization percentage of my program(using pid).

I am using C programming, Linux environment.

Comment: top or htop both give the CPU load

Comment: What is the difference between 'cpu utilisation percentage' and 'cpu load'?

Comment: I have written a simple C program which forks two child processes and both the child processes continuously run infinite for-loops. Now when I observe the output of htop, it showing cpu% as 99 for both the processes. From this I came to know that, the processes are getting 99% of processor. But that is not the load on the cpu by those processors   :(

Comment: When a program is running, it is using 100% of its core. When it is waiting, like for I/O, it is using zero. So any percent in between is just a time-average. What you want is something that alternates a simple loop and I/O so that, long term, it spends 4 times as much time doing I/O as it spends cranking.

Comment: Traditionally, load is calculated as  sum(# processes runnable at the end of each time slice)/(# time slices) for a certain amount of time.
So if there are two processes runnable at the end of each time slice, your load will be 2, irrespective of the number of CPUs present.

Since the CFS (completely fair scheduler) the concept of a time slice is not used anymore, so the definition has slightly changed. conceptually, the calculation hasn't changed, though.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are probably looking for is `getrusage`. It fills `struct rusage`. There are two members of the struct you are interested in:

1. `ru_utime` - user CPU time used
2. `ru_stime` - system CPU time used

You can call the function at regular intervals of time and based on the results you can **estimate** the cpu load (e.g. in percentage) of **your own process**.

If you want to get it at the system level, then you need to read (and parse) **/proc/stat**
file (also at regular intervals), see [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm).

Comment: You could also read and parse `/proc/loadavg`  to get the average system load, and you could use `usleep` or `nanosleep`  inside a process to make it sleep for a small delay (useful to "lower" the system load).

Comment: Yes, this is another option, which may (or may not) be even better solution depending on what he actually wants to achieve.